# Payload error in Cloud Functions for Firebase Messaging

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, google-cloud-functions

I wrote a cloud function using Cloud Functions for Firebase that sends notifications to certain topics of Firebase Messaging. The final parts of the function define the payload to be sent, then sends it:

```
// javascript code in cloud functions
const payload = {
      'notification': {
        'title': `${toTitleCase(name)} just logged an event`,
        'body': `${events[eventType]} for ${toTitleCase(petName)}`,
        'data': {
            'personSent': userSent 
        }
      }
    };
console.log(payload);
admin.messaging().sendToTopic(pet_Id, payload);
```

However, I'm getting the error log in my Firebase console:

> Error: Messaging payload contains an invalid value for the "notification.data" property. Values must be strings.

When I logout the payload I confirmed it is all strings:

```
{ notification: 
   { title: 'Turtle Dude just logged an event',
     body: 'Walk for Beer',
     data: { personSent: 'mfsP8U0qDdQL4rrrbXp6K0YsF423' } } }
```

However, when I send the same payload from my iPhone app (which I'm trying to avoid since that means I have to store the messaging private key on the client side) I am able to attach the extra data I want to send just fine:

```swift
// Swift code in iPhone app
let body: [String: Any] = ["to": "/topics/\(currentPet)",
                            "priority" : "high",
                            "notification" : [
                                "body" : "\(events[eventType]) for \(petsName.localizedCapitalized)",
                                "title" : "\(myName.localizedCapitalized) just logged an event",
                                "data" : ["personSent": myId]
                              ]
                           ]
```

How can I accomplish adding additional data in my cloud function like I do in my Swift code?

Comment: I think you need to promote your `data` up a level: `{notification: {}, data: {}}`

Comment: Well since I'm only sending one field under `data` I just made `myId` the value to `data` instead of nesting it. Not really sure why it didn't work though.

Comment: Hi @MarksCode. Is it still not working after modifying the payload like Michael Bleigh mentioned? It's a bit unclear from your comment.

Comment: I just changed it to `'data' : userSent` instead of nesting it and that works. Its fine since I'm only sending one piece of data but incase I want to send more than one I'll try Michael's suggestion.

Answer (score 15):

As others explained in the comments, the `data` object should go inside `payload`,
 NOT inside `notification`.

Try the following code:

```
// javascript code in cloud functions
const payload = {
      'notification': {
        'title': `${toTitleCase(name)} just logged an event`,
        'body': `${events[eventType]} for ${toTitleCase(petName)}`,
      }, 
      // NOTE: The 'data' object is inside payload, not inside notification
      'data': { 
            'personSent': userSent 
      }
    };
console.log(payload);
admin.messaging().sendToTopic(pet_Id, payload);
```

Comment: I don't know how are you managing this, but at least using typescript I have the same error and what's worse is that the definition of `DataMessagePayload` is a map of strings to string `[key: string]: string;`. Which means that all properties must be string apparently.

Comment: It's mandatory to have strings in your data.
https://github.com/firebase/firebase-admin-node/issues/424#issuecomment-447666532

Answer (score 2):

Along with Diego's answer, I would like to point out a crucial detail for anyone who visits this message in the future...
"Make sure to PARSE ANY ObjectId's to String when assigning it to a value for any key inside DATA"
.
This has pretty much been the most unfigurable problem while dealing with FCM. And was the prime factor in solving my problem.

Comment: Great! This is very important

Answer (score 0):

Whoever might experience this error by now. Using node V14.7.0 on Windows and firebase-admin version ^9.6.0 seem to work perfectly, I had no issue. However, when deploying it on Bitnami, the error was thrown. To solve it, I had to parse the object `someObject` properties to be assigned to 'data' to string:

```
//someObject.property_throwing the error should be parsed to string

data: someObject
```